# How to block visitors from particular country with nginx and GeoIP Module

Tags: nginx, networking, geolocation, ubuntu-16.04, geoip2

I want to block a particular country's visitors to access my website `www.mainwebsite.com` through Nginx and GeoIP Module.

First I tried on `www.test.com`. What steps I followed on test website,`www.test.com`, before trying on `www.mainwebsite.com`

1. Installing GeoIP:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt-get install geoip-database
```

2. Check GeoIP Module is installed  or not:

```
nginx -V 2>&1|grep --color=always with-http_geoip_module
```

3. Download the GeoIP Database:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/nginx/GeoIP/
```

Placed GeoIP.dat file to /etc/nginx/GeoIP/ location.

4. Configure Nginx and Virtual Host.
   sudo vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
http{
##
# Basic Settings
##
      geoip_country /etc/nginx/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;
      map $geoip_country_code $allowed_country {
        default yes;
        IN no;
      }

}
```

Save and exit.

5. sudo vi /etc/nginx/site-available/test.com
   Added the map line in starting outside of server{......}

```
map $geoip_country_code $allowed_country {
 default yes;
 IN no;
}
```

After that, inside server{......} setting, add the IF condition.

```
if ($allowed_country = no) {
     return 403;
 }
```

Save and exit.

6. Reload and restart nginx

```
sudo service nginx reload
sudo service nginx restart
```

So `www.test.com` is directly hosted on Ec2 instance `test-server-01`  with public Network/IP, Blocking worked and users were not able to access from blocked country.

`www.mainwebsite.com` is hosted to classic load balancer and ec2 instances are attached to classic load balancer.

For testing, I created 2 replica server of `test-server-01` server and created new load balancer and attached both replica servers behind the load balancer and pointed `www.test.com` to new load balancer. But Geo Country blocking didn't work so I added 2 below lines above IF condition which (If condition) is mentioned in point 5, then blocking worked.

```
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
```

Now I followed the same steps 1 to 6 for `www.mainwebsite.com` and made the changes in `nginx.conf` & `/etc/nginx/site-available/mainwebsite.com` but country blocking didn't work.

I have a doubt here that, for `www.test.com`, the contents of `/etc/nginx/site-available/test.com` and linked file `/etc/nginx/site-enabled/test.com` are same.

But for `www.mainwebsite.com`, the content of files `/etc/nginx/site-available/mainwebsite.com` and `/etc/nginx/site-enabled/mainwebsite.com` are not same.

`/etc/nginx/site-enabled/mainwebsite.com` has some extra contents like:
Outside of server{} block-

```
# Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
   ~image/                     max;
    application/font-woff      max;
}
```

and inside the server{} block.

```
    server_name  www.mainwebsite.com;
    rewrite ^/blog/blogs$ https://www.mainwebsite.com/blogs permanent;
    rewrite ^/companies https://www.mainwebsite.com.com/company permanent;
    rewrite ^/events-2/* https://www.mainwebsite.com/events permanent;
```

Is this actual reason that's why country blocking is not working? Or there can be other reasons? Please help me out.